# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsa after 3 dec Firebase update

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, manifest, dex

I don't know what to do regarding this:
I updated to the latest gradle from here: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/
I have the latest gradle plugin 3.2.1.
Also updated to latest google play libraries from here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
And Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android
In my main build.gradle I have this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()

    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
}
```

And my app build.gradle I have this buildscript dependencies:

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.1"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services plugin
}
```

And this normal dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:transition:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2+'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1+'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0+'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar')
implementation 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
implementation 'io.smooch:core:latest.release'
implementation 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'
implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.+'
implementation 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
implementation 'com.github.kaknazaveshtakipishi:PermissionEverywhere:1.0.2'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation(
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
)
implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.1'
implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.brandongogetap:stickyheaders:0.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.Chils17:OdometerLibrary:687d5ac1e9'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzrv

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/16.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/17.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/18.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/19.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/20.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/21.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/22.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/23.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/24.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/25.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/26.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/27.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/28.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/29.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/30.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/31.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/32.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/33.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/34.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/35.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/36.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/37.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/38.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/39.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/40.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/41.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/42.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/43.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/46.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/47.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/48.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/49.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/50.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/51.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/52.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/53.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/54.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/55.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/56.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/57.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/58.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/59.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/60.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/61.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/62.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/63.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/64.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/65.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/66.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/67.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/68.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/69.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/70.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/71.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/72.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/73.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/74.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/75.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/76.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/77.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/78.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/79.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/80.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/81.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/82.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/83.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/84.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/85.jar, /Users/alinrosu/Workspace/passenger-android/passenger/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/86.jar
```

## EDIT

Removing `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'` from the app makes it work. But I need my analytics inside, any ideea how to make analytics work with this?

Answer (score 1):

I made a clean android app and added the same manifest, and then played with the build.gradle file.
I noticed that removing:
 `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'` worked.

So I google a bit and found here the latest version:  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases
I updated to 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'` and it now works

Comment: Thanks! You saved me after 6 hours. Google is still listing 16.0.4 on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement **multidex** in your project. It will solve your problem. I am facing the same problem in some project while adding too many libraries in the project.

To enable multidex in your project visit below link:

[Enable Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)

I hope it will resolve your problem.

Try to update your Gradle dependency and remove the same libraries form project. For reference refer below Gradle dependency code which I make from your code. It will help you to resolve it. And also read it's my comments in that code.

```
dependencies {
    // Remove or Comment this line as we does not require to implement jar file.
   // If required then implement particular library one by one
   //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:transition:28.0.0'

  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

  implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

  // Note: Try to use only one ok HTTP library from below.
  // In your code, you are using OKHttp and okhttp3 both library. 
  // Just use anyone.
  // And use same version for okhttp and okhttp url connection
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
  //Remove this jar file and use below gradle line to use this library
  //implementation files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar')
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'

  //Note: This one is latest OKHttp Library which you have to in your project
  //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
  //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.0'

  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
  //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

  implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

  // This is your firebase analytics library. Try to use it instead of google analytics.
  // Remove google analytics
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'

  implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7@aar') {
      transitive = true;
  }

  //Remove this jar file and use below gradle line to use this library
  //implementation files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
  implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

  implementation 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'

  implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

  //Check out requirement for rxjava implementation and its steps
  //implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
  implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8'

  //Note: This is latest library for RxJava version 2 which you should have to use
  //implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.4"

  implementation 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.2'

  //Note: Try to implement library with its version number.
  //Check out below library implementation steps and notes for below library
  //implementation 'io.smooch:core:latest.release'
  //implementation 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'
  implementation 'io.smooch:core:5.15.0'
  implementation 'io.smooch:ui:5.15.0'

  implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
  implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:recyclerviewheader2:2.0.1'
  implementation 'com.brandongogetap:stickyheaders:0.5.1'

  implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.0.3'
  implementation 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'

  implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
  implementation 'com.github.kaknazaveshtakipishi:PermissionEverywhere:1.0.2'

  /*implementation(
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
  )*/
  implementation(
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.7'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.7'],
          [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.7']
  )

  implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'

  implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'

  implementation 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'

  // Check Facebook SDK integration notes and try to implement only required part of SDK from notes.
  //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'

  implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.15.1'

  implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'

  implementation 'com.github.Chils17:OdometerLibrary:687d5ac1e9'

  implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'
}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If possible from above libraries remove unused libraries

Comment: Are you referring to this:

       `defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1400
        versionName '3.5'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }` ? If so, it's already enabled

Comment: Please check my edit. I removed analytics and it works, but I need that, any ideea how I can keep it there? tried with different versions now

Comment: In your project file, you are using many libraries for your projects. From all that libraries some libraries are used for the same purpose or some libraries have a different version which is dependent on other libraries. So try to add the same version library which is dependent on each other. I have made your gradle file dependency with the latest version so check out that one in my edit. Also, read my comments which I note in that gradle code